# Authentication in SwiftUI App Using JSON Web Token (JWT) - WordPress REST

Tags: swift, wordpress, web-services, swiftui, jwt

So far I can successfully login with JWT to WordPress in SwiftUI. I'm able to save the Token and at every app relaunch I connect the user automatically. Next i want to fetch the user email address on the User Profile page in SwiftUI.

Is first time i am trying to login to a website trough swift app. I have studied JWT documentation but is not clear for me - they don't provide real life examples.

So far i understand how to use the Token, save it and then every new request send it again from swift in order to fetch "non-public" data.

They give us two end points:
/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token   ->This is the entry point for the JWT Authentication.
and
/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token/validate   ->This is a simple helper endpoint to validate a token

But where are all the wordpress endpoints? . For example:

- /wp-json/wp/v2/users/me  -> data of the user's profile.

What "data" i have to send from swiftUI app, and on witch end point in order to:

- signing, logout, login
- publish a listing or blog post
- read user data: bookmarks, email, nick name, address, etc
- update user data

So far i manage only to login(JWT job), but I can't fetch user email after is authenticated.
Can you please help?!

1. From Postman POST request at: https://mywebsite/wp-json/wp/v2/users/me
   i get response in json:

```javascript
    { 
      "id": 1, 
      "username": "admin", 
      "name": "admin", 
      "first_name": "", 
      "last_name": "", 
       "email": "admin@mywebsite.com", 
      "locale": "en_US", "nickname": "admin", "slug": "admin", 
    }
```

In my SwifUI app i doo this steps to connect and fetch the user data:

1: Webservice to get Token and log in

```swift
class Webservice: ObservableObject {
      @Published var accounts: [Account] = []
    

    func login(username: String, password: String, completion: @escaping (Result<String, AuthenticationError>) -> Void) {
      
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://mywebsite/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token") else {
            completion(.failure(.custom(errorMessage: "URL is not correct")))
            return
        }
        let body = LoginRequestBody(username: username, password: password)
        
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        
        request.httpBody = try? JSONEncoder().encode(body)
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                completion(.failure(.custom(errorMessage: "No data")))
                return
            }
            
            try! JSONDecoder().decode(LoginResponse.self, from: data)
            
            guard let loginResponse = try? JSONDecoder().decode(LoginResponse.self, from: data) else {
                completion(.failure(.invalidCredentials))
                return
            }
            
            guard let token = loginResponse.token else {
                completion(.failure(.invalidCredentials))
                return
            }
            
            completion(.success(token))
            
        }.resume()
        
    }
    // get user email adress
    
    func getUserProfile(token: String, completion: @escaping (Result<[Account], NetworkError>) -> Void) {
        
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://mywebsite/wp-json/wp/v2/users/me") else {
            completion(.failure(.invalidURL))
            return
        }

        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.addValue("Bearer \(token)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        request.addValue("application/json \(token)", forHTTPHeaderField: "accept")
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                completion(.failure(.noData))
                return
            }
            
            guard let accounts = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Account].self, from: data) else {
                completion(.failure(.decodingError))
                return
            }
            
            completion(.success(accounts))

        }.resume()
        
        
    }
    
    // Function to login again use saved token
    
    func loginAgain(username: String, password: String, completion: @escaping (Result<String, AuthenticationError>) -> Void) {

        guard let url = URL(string: "https://mywebsite/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token") else {
            completion(.failure(.custom(errorMessage: "URL is not correct")))
            return
        }
        let body = LoginRequestBody(username: username, password: password)

        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        request.httpBody = try? JSONEncoder().encode(body)

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in

            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                completion(.failure(.custom(errorMessage: "No data")))
                return
            }

            try! JSONDecoder().decode(LoginResponse.self, from: data)

            guard let loginResponse = try? JSONDecoder().decode(LoginResponse.self, from: data) else {
                completion(.failure(.invalidCredentials))
                return
            }

            guard let token = loginResponse.token else {
                completion(.failure(.invalidCredentials))
                return
            }

            completion(.success(token))

        }.resume()

    }
}
```

2. Login View Model

```swift
class LoginViewModel: ObservableObject {
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    var username: String = ""
    var password: String = ""
    @Published var isAuthenticated: Bool = false
    
    func login() {
        
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        
        Webservice().login(username: username, password: password) { result in
            switch result {
                case .success(let token):
                    defaults.setValue(token, forKey: "jsonwebtoken")
                    print(token)
                    print(self.username)
                    print(self.password)
                    defaults.setValue(self.username, forKey: "userName")
                    defaults.setValue(self.password, forKey: "userPass")
                   
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.isAuthenticated = true
                    }
                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
    // automatic login with all data from defaults memory
    func loginAgain() {

       let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        let userna = defaults.string(forKey: "userName") ?? "userName"
        let userpa = defaults.string(forKey: "userPass") ?? "userPass"

        Webservice().loginAgain(username: userna, password: userpa ) { result in
            switch result {
                case .success(let token):
                    defaults.setValue(token, forKey: "jsonwebtoken")

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.isAuthenticated = true
                    }
                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
    // when signout all data will be deleted from defaults
    func signout() {
           
           let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
           defaults.removeObject(forKey: "jsonwebtoken")
           defaults.removeObject(forKey: "userName")
           defaults.removeObject(forKey: "userPass")
           DispatchQueue.main.async {
               self.isAuthenticated = false
           }
           
       }
    
}
```

So far all good. Still i can get any other data from the user json

```swift
struct AccountViewModel {
    
    var account: Account
    let id = UUID()
    var link: String {
        return account.link
    }
    var email: String {
        return account.email
    }
}

class AccountListViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var accounts: [AccountViewModel] = []
    
    func getAllAccounts() {

        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        guard let token = defaults.string(forKey: "jsonwebtoken") else {
            return
        }

        Webservice().getUserProfile(token: token) { (result) in
            switch result {
                case .success(let accounts):
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.accounts = accounts.map(AccountViewModel.init)
                    }
                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

3. Finally in one view i try to fetch user email only if is authenticated.

```swift
      struct UserProfile: View {
      @StateObject private var loginVM = LoginViewModel()
          var body: some View {
          
          
             if loginVM.isAuthenticated {         
                   ForEach(accountListVM.accounts, id: \.id) { account in
                            UserProfile()
                        }
                    Button(action: {
                    
                        accountListVM.getAllAccounts()
                        
                    }, label: {
                     Text("Fetch user Email")
                    })
              }
           }
         }
```

User profile view:

```swift
struct Account: Decodable {
    var email: String
    var link: String  
}

struct UserProfile: View {
    var my: Account?
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            Text(my!.email)
                .font(.body)
            Text(my!.link)
                .font(.body)

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered to add the user email etc. to the JWT contents? Non-sensitive data can be contained in JWT and then saved in localStorage for example for frontend use between hits to the token verification endpoint. It's the user who provides the credentials when logging in, so you should not have to search for their details on the backend from the point they're logged in, unless you need to verify this data on every api hit.